# Bootstrap Typeahead with Backbone memory leak

Tags: backbone.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using Bootstrap Typeahead along with Backbone to display data fetched from the server based on user input. The backing Backbone collection, which is used to store the fetched data, is created once on app startup. The collection is re-used for every new search in Typeahead.

The issue I am having is the browser memory usage keeps going up every time users searches for something. My question is really how can I make sure the old result/data in collection is garbage collected when the new one comes in? Also is re-using the same collection for new search the right way to go?

**The collection js file**

```
define([
"data",
"backbone",
"vent"
],
function (data, Backbone, vent) {
    var SearchCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model:Backbone.Model,

        url:function () {
            return data.getUrl("entitysearch");
        },

        initialize:function (models, options) {
            var self=this;
            this.requestAborted = false;
            this.categories = (options && options.categories) || ['counterparty', 'company', 'user'];
            this.onItemSelected = options.onItemSelected;
            this.selectedId = options.selectedId; // should be prefixed with type eg. "company-12345"
            _.bindAll(this, "entitySelected");

            vent.bindTo(vent, "abortSearchAjax", function () {
                this.requestAborted = true;
            }, this);
        },

        search:function (criteria) {
            var self = this,
                results = [];

            // abort any existing requests
            if (this.searchRequest) {
                this.searchRequest.abort();
            }
            self.requestAborted= false;
            this.searchRequest = this.fetch({
                data:$.param({
                    query:criteria,
                    types: this.mapEntityTypesToCodes(this.categories),
                    fields:'ANY',
                    max: 500
                })
            })

            .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (!self.requestAborted){
                        results = self.processResponse(response);
                    }

            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 if(errorThrown === "Unauthorized" || errorThrown === "Forbidden") {
                    alert("Either you do not have the right permissions to search for entities or you do not have a valid SSO token." +
                        " Reload the page to update your SSO token.");
                 }
            })
            .always(function(){
                if (!self.requestAborted){
                    self.reset(results);
                    self.trigger('searchComplete');
                }
                });
        },
        /**
         * Backbone parse won't work here as it requires you to modify the original response object not create a new one.
         * @param data
         * @return {Array}
         */
        processResponse:function (response) {
            var self = this,
                result = [];

            _.each(response, function (val, key, list) {
                if (key !== 'query') {
                    _.map(val, function (v, k, l) {
                        var id;
                        v.type = self.mapEntityShortName(key);
                        id = v.id;
                        v.id = v.type + '-' + v.id;
                        v.displayId = id;
                    });
                    result = result.concat(val);
                }
            });
            return result;
        },

        mapEntityTypesToCodes:function (types) {
            var codes = [],
                found = false;
            _.each(types, function(el, index, list) {
                {
                    switch (el) {
                        case 'counterparty':
                            codes.push('L5');
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        case 'company':
                            codes.push('L3');
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        case 'user':
                            codes.push('user');
                            found = true;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            if (!found) {
                throw "mapEntityTypesToCodes - requires an array containing one or more types - counterparty, company, user";
            }
            return codes.join(',');
        },

        mapEntityShortName: function(name) {
            switch (name) {
                case 'parties':
                    return 'counterparty';
                    break;
                case 'companies':
                    return 'company';
                    break;
                case 'users':
                    return 'user';
                    break;
            }
        },

        entitySelected:function (item) {
            var model,
                obj = JSON.parse(item),
                data;

            model = this.get(obj.id);
            if (model) {
                model.set('selected', true);
                data = model.toJSON();
                this.selectedId = obj.id;
                //correct the id to remove the type eg. company-
                data.id = data.displayId;
                this.onItemSelected && this.onItemSelected(data);
            } else {
                throw "entitySelected - model not found";
            }
        },

        openSelectedEntity: function() {
            var model = this.get(this.selectedId);
            if (model) {
                vent.trigger('entityOpened', {
                    id: this.selectedId.split('-')[1],
                    name: model.get('name'),
                    type: model.get('type')
                });
            }
        },

        entityClosed:function (id) {
            var model;

            model = this.where({
                id:id
            });
            if (model.length) {
                model[0].set('selected', false);
            }
        }

    });

    return SearchCollection;
});
```

**The View js file**

```
define([
"backbone",
"hbs!modules/search/templates/search",
"bootstrap-typeahead"
],

function (Backbone, tpl) {
    return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        events: {
            'click .action-open-entity': 'openEntity'
        },

        className: 'modSearch',

        template:{
            type:'handlebars',
            template:tpl
        },

        initialize:function (options) {
            _.bindAll(this, "render", "sorter", "renderSearchResults", "typeaheadSource");
            this.listen();
            this.categoryNames = options.categoryNames;
            this.showCategoryNames = options.showCategoryNames;
            this.autofocus = options.autofocus;
            this.initValue = options.initValue;
            this.disabled = options.disabled;
            this.updateValueOnSelect = options.updateValueOnSelect;
            this.showLink = options.showLink;
            this.resultsLength = 1500;
        },

        listen:function () {
            this.collection.on('searchComplete', this.renderSearchResults);
            this.collection.on('change:selected', this.highlightedItemChange, this);
        },

        resultsFormatter:function () {
            var searchResults = [],
                that = this;

            this.collection.each(function (result) {
                searchResults.push(that._resultFormatter(result));
            });
            return searchResults;
        },

        _resultFormatter:function (model) {
            var result = {
                name:model.get('name'),
                id:model.get('id'),
                displayId: model.get('displayId'),
                aliases:model.get('aliases'),
                type:model.get('type'),
                marketsPriority:model.get('marketsPriority')
            };
            if (model.get('ssoId')) {
                result.ssoId = model.get('ssoId');
            }
            return JSON.stringify(result);
        },

        openEntity: function() {
            this.collection.openSelectedEntity();
        },

        serializeData:function () {
            return {
                categoryNames:this.categoryNames,
                showCategoryNames: this.showCategoryNames,
                initValue:this.initValue,
                autofocus:this.autofocus,
                showLink:this.showLink
            };
        },

        onRender:function () {
            var self = this,
                debouncedSearch;

            if (this.disabled === true) {
                this.$('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                debouncedSearch = _.debounce(this.typeaheadSource, 500);
                this.typeahead = this.$('.typeahead')
                    .typeahead({
                        source: debouncedSearch,
                        categories:{
                            'counterparty':'Counterparties',
                            'company':'Companies',
                            'user':'Users'
                        },
                        minLength:3,
                        multiSelect:true,
                        items:this.resultsLength,
                        onItemSelected:self.collection.entitySelected,
                        renderItem:this.renderDropdownItem,
                        matcher: this.matcher,
                        sorter:this.sorter,
                        updateValueOnSelect:this.updateValueOnSelect
                    })
                    .data('typeahead');
                $('.details').hide();
            }

        },

        onClose: function(){
            this.typeahead.$menu.remove();
        },

        highlightedItemChange:function (model) {
            this.typeahead.changeItemHighlight(model.get('displayId'), model.get('selected'));
        },

        renderSearchResults:function () {
            this.searchCallback(this.resultsFormatter());
        },

        typeaheadSource:function (query, searchCallback) {
            this.searchCallback = searchCallback;
            this.collection.search(query);
        },

        /**
         * Called from typeahead plugin
         * @param item
         * @return {String}
         */
        renderDropdownItem:function (item) {
            var entity,
                marketsPriority = '',
                aliases = '';
            if (!item) {
                return item;
            }
            if (typeof item === 'string') {
                entity = JSON.parse(item);
                if (entity.marketsPriority && (entity.marketsPriority === "Y")) {
                    marketsPriority = '<span class="marketsPriority">M</span>';
                }
                if (entity.aliases && (entity.aliases.constructor === Array) && entity.aliases.length) {
                    aliases = ' (' + entity.aliases.join(', ') +  ') ';
                }
                if (entity.type === "user"){
                    entity.displayId = entity.ssoId;
                }
                return [entity.name || '', aliases, ' (', entity.displayId || '', ')', marketsPriority].join('');
            }
            return item;
        },

        matcher: function(item){
            return item;
        },

        /**
         * Sort typeahead results - called from typeahead plugin
         * @param items
         * @param query
         * @return {Array}
         */
        sorter:function (items, query) {
            var results = {},
                reducedResults,
                unmatched,
                filteredItems,
                types = ['counterparty', 'company', 'user'],
                props = ['displayId', 'name', 'aliases', 'ssoId'],
                type,
                prop;

            query = $.trim(query);
            for (var i = 0, j = types.length; i < j; i++) {
                type = types[i];
                filteredItems = this._filterByType(items, type);
                for (var k = 0, l = props.length; k < l; k++) {
                    prop = props[k];
                    unmatched = [];
                    if (!results[type]) {
                        results[type] = [];
                    }
                    results[type] = results[type].concat(this._filterByProperty(query, filteredItems, prop, unmatched));
                    filteredItems = unmatched;
                }
            }

            reducedResults = this._reduceItems(results, types, this.resultsLength);

            return reducedResults;
        },

        /**
         * Sort helper - match query string against a specific property
         * @param query
         * @param item
         * @param fieldToMatch
         * @param resultArrays
         * @return {Boolean}
         * @private
         */
        _matchProperty:function (query, item, fieldToMatch, resultArrays) {

            if (fieldToMatch.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
                resultArrays.beginsWith.push(item);
            } else if (~fieldToMatch.indexOf(query)) resultArrays.caseSensitive.push(item)
            else if (~fieldToMatch.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase())) resultArrays.caseInsensitive.push(item)
            else if(this._fieldConatins(query, fieldToMatch, resultArrays)) resultArrays.caseInsensitive.push(item)
            else return false;
            return true;
        },

        _fieldConatins:function (query, fieldToMatch, resultArrays) {
            var matched = false;
            var queryList = query.split(" ");
            _.each(queryList, function(queryItem) {
                if(fieldToMatch.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryItem.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                    matched = true;
                    return;
                }
            });
            return matched;
        },

        /**
         * Sort helper - filter result set by property type (name, id)
         * @param query
         * @param items
         * @param prop
         * @param unmatchedArray
         * @return {Array}
         * @private
         */
        _filterByProperty:function (query, items, prop, unmatchedArray) {
            var resultArrays = {
                    beginsWith:[],
                    caseSensitive:[],
                    caseInsensitive:[],
                    contains:[]
                },
                itemObj,
                item,
                isMatched;

            while (item = items.shift()) {
                itemObj = JSON.parse(item);
                isMatched = itemObj[prop] && this._matchProperty(query, item, itemObj[prop].toString(), resultArrays);
                if (!isMatched && unmatchedArray) {
                    unmatchedArray.push(item);
                }
            }
            return resultArrays.beginsWith.concat(resultArrays.caseSensitive, resultArrays.caseInsensitive, resultArrays.contains);
        },

        /**
         * Sort helper - filter result set by entity type (counterparty, company, user)
         * @param {Array} items
         * @param {string} type
         * @return {Array}
         * @private
         */
        _filterByType:function (items, type) {
            var item,
                itemObj,
                filtered = [];

            for (var i = 0, j = items.length; i < j; i++) {
                item = items[i];
                itemObj = JSON.parse(item);
                if (itemObj.type === type) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                }
            }
            return filtered;
        },

        /**
         * Sort helper - reduce the result set down and split between the entity types (counterparty, company, user)
         * @param results
         * @param types
         * @param targetLength
         * @return {Array}
         * @private
         */
        _reduceItems:function (results, types, targetLength) {
            var categoryLength,
                type,
                len,
                diff,
                reduced = [],
                reducedEscaped = [];

            categoryLength = Math.floor(targetLength / types.length);

            for (var i = 0, j = types.length; i < j; i++) {
                type = types[i];
                len = results[type].length;
                diff = categoryLength - len;
                if (diff >= 0) { // actual length was shorter
                    reduced = reduced.concat(results[type].slice(0, len));
                    categoryLength = categoryLength + Math.floor(diff / (types.length - (i + 1)));
                } else {
                    reduced = reduced.concat(results[type].slice(0, categoryLength));
                }
            }
            _.each(reduced, function(item) {
                item = item.replace(/\'/g,"`");
                reducedEscaped.push(item);
            });
            return reducedEscaped;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: please add some code samples. without seeing the code, there is no way of knowing what is going on.

Comment: @DerickBailey - Maybe simplifying my question will help - All I want to know is if I have a collection which continuously fetches new data from server what happens to the old data which it held up until new data was fetched? Also since I am using the same collection to fetch new data I cannot simply dereference the collection object for it to quality for garbage collection.